# Randomly select from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two related numpy arrays, `X` and `y`. I need to select `n` random rows from `X` and store this in an array, the corresponding `y` value and the appends to it the index of the points randomly selected.

I have another array `index` which stores a list of index which I dont want to sample.

How can I do this?

Sample data:

```
index = [2,3]
X = np.array([[0.3,0.7],[0.5,0.5] ,[0.2,0.8], [0.1,0.9]])
y = np.array([[0], [1], [0], [1]])
```

If these `X`'s were randomly selected (where `n=2`):

```
randomylSelected = np.array([[0.3,0.7],[0.5,0.5]])
```

the desired output would be:

```
index = [0,1,2,3]
randomlySelectedY = [0,1]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So, is `randomylSelected` given or to be created?

Comment: To be created by randomly selecting `n` rows from `X`. @Divakar

Comment: Could you please clarify how your `index` changes from `[2,3]` to `[0,1]` when it's not sampled? What's the purpose of the `index` and how does it relate to the other arrays?

Comment: @MSeifert `index` contains a list of items already sampled which should not be sampled again.

Comment: @scutnex In that case: Thanks for the clarification but you should rather ask a new question instead of changing the question (after it received answers) in such fundamental ways. Could you please rollback your question to the original version and ask a new question?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can create random indices with [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
n = 2  # for 2 random indices
index = np.random.choice(X.shape[0], n, replace=False)
```

Then you just need to index your arrays with the result:

```
x_random = X[index]
y_random = Y[index]
```

Answer (score 9):

just to wrap @MSeifert 's answer in a function:

```
def random_sample(arr: numpy.array, size: int = 1) -> numpy.array:
    return arr[np.random.choice(len(arr), size=size, replace=False)]
```

useage:

```
randomly_selected_y = random_sample(Y)
```

Comment: Seriously why is there no function for this, that is such a common use case. So annoying.