# Generate random numbers from a list of numbers

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a list of numbers:

```
data = [15, 30, 45]
```

how to generate  a list of N numbers taken randomly from this `data` list? To get result as:

```
new_data = [15,15, 30, 45, 15,45, 30, 15, 45, 30, 45, 45, 45, 15, ...]

np.random.randint(15, high=45, size=N) # does not help here
```

What `numpy` functions to use for this?

Comment: Does the solution have to use a numpy function?

Comment: Ideally, yes. In any case numbers should be normally distributed.

Comment: Why do you want to use NumPy, especially since the example data you've given is in the form of plain Python lists?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43506766/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/306400/11301900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `np.random.choice`:

```
import numpy as np 
data=[15,30,45]
N = 50
new_list = np.random.choice(data,N)
```

Edit: Using `random.sample()` won't work as the sampling is done without replacement, therefore samples can't exceed length of the original data.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the code and forgot to change the import as I used `random` first.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.random.choice` can do this:

```
import numpy

data = [15, 30, 45]
N = 20
new_data = numpy.random.choice(data, N)
print(new_data)
```

https://ideone.com/ECqtJ3

Answer (score 1):

For a non-Numpy solution:

```
import random


l = [15, 30, 45]
N = 30
result = [random.choice(l) for i in range(N)]

# outputs: [15, 30, 15, 45, 15, 15, 30, 15, 30, 45, 15, 45, 30, 15, 30, 15, 15, 45, 30, 45, 30, 45, 45, 15, 15, 45, 30, 45, 45, 45]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

data = [15, 30, 45]
new_data = []
N = 14

for i in range (0, N) :
    new_data.append(random.choice(data))

print("Data: ", data)
print("\nNew data :", new_data)

input("\n\nPress Enter to continue...")
```

https://ideone.com/5iD9U7

Comment: Yes, or a list comprehension is cleaner: `new_data = [random.choice(data) for _ in range(N)]`

Comment: Works like a charm!